# Hurwitz numbers and $t$-cores

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, modular-forms, symmetric-groups, partitions

For integers $k \geq 0$ and $d \geq 1$ let $H(k,d)$
be the *Hurwitz* number which, for the purposes
of this posting, will be defined by:

\begin{equation}
 H(k,d)
\, := \ d! \,  \sum_{\lambda \, \vdash d}
\, \nu_{\scriptscriptstyle T}^k(\lambda)
\ \ \text{where} \ \nu_{\scriptscriptstyle T}(\lambda) := \binom{d}{2} \cdot
{{\chi^\lambda_{\scriptscriptstyle T}} \over {\dim(\lambda)} } 
\end{equation}

and where $\chi^\lambda$ is the
character value of the irreducible representation $V_\lambda$ of the symmetric group $S_d$ corresponding to the partition $\lambda \vdash d$ evaluated at any representative transposition (taken from the conjugacy class $T$ of all transpositions) and where $\dim(\lambda)$ is the dimension of $V_\lambda$. The Hurwitz number $H(k,d)$ can be interpreted, using the Verlinde formula, as counting the
the number of homomorphisms (up to conjugation in $S_d$)

\begin{equation}
\rho : \pi_1 \Big( \Bbb{T}^2_k , \, \mathrm{base \, point}\Big)
\longrightarrow S_d
\end{equation}

where $\Bbb{T}^2_k$ is the 2-torus with $k$ punctures.
We can assemble these Hurwitz numbers into the following
bivariate generating function

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{ll}
H(x;q) 
&\displaystyle = \
1 \ + \ \sum_{d \geq 1} \, \sum_{k \geq 0} \, H(k,d) \, {x^k \over {k!}} \, q^d \\ 
&\displaystyle = \ 1 \ + \ \sum_{\lambda \ne \emptyset} \, q^{|\lambda|} \, \exp \big\{ x \, \nu_{\scriptscriptstyle T}(\lambda) \big\}
\end{array}
\end{equation}

whose logarithm has a "genus" expansion

\begin{equation}
\log H(x;\tau) =  F_1(\tau) \ + \ \sum_{g \geq 2} \, F_g(\tau) \,
{x^{2g-2} \over {(2g-2)!}} 
\end{equation}

where we set $q = e^{2\pi i \tau}$ and each $\tau$-series $F_g(\tau)$ is known to be a quasi-modular form.

Now let $t \geq 2$ be an integer and let us consider the following
*$t$-core analogues*:

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{l}
\displaystyle H_t(x;q) 
\, := \ 1 \ + \ \sum_{\stackrel{\scriptstyle \text{$t$-cores}}{\lambda \,\ne \, \emptyset}} \, q^{|\lambda|} \, \exp \
\big\{ x \, \nu_{\scriptscriptstyle T}(\lambda) \big\} \\
\displaystyle F_{g; \, t}(\tau) \, := \ \text{
the coefficient of} \ {x^{2g-2} \over {(2g-2)!}} \ \text{in}
\ \log H_t(x;\tau)
\end{array}
\end{equation}

**Question 1:** Does the generating function $H_t(x;q)$ have
a nice closed expression, e.g. some sort of product formula?

**Question 2:** Does the $\tau$-series $F_{g; \, t}(\tau)$ have any
kind of modular property?

thanks, ines.

**Post Script:**
As a kind of stupid example, consider the case of $2$-cores, which are precisely the *stair-case* partitions. The Murnaghan-Nakayama rule tells us that $\chi^\lambda_{\scriptscriptstyle T}$ can be evaluated recursively as the (signed) sum of dimensions $\dim(\mu)$ of partitions $\mu \vdash |\lambda| -2$ obtained by removing *skew-hooks* of size $2$ from the border of $\lambda$, i.e.

\begin{equation}
\chi^\lambda_{\scriptscriptstyle T} \ = \
\sum_{\stackrel{\scriptstyle \lambda \, = \, \mu + \sigma}{\sigma \, \vdash \, 2}} \, \big(-1 \big)^{\#(\sigma)-1} \, \dim(\mu)
\end{equation}

where $\#(\sigma)$ is the number of parts of $\sigma$. Of course there are **no** skew-hooks of size $2$ which can be excised from a stair-case partition, so $\chi^\lambda_{\scriptscriptstyle T} = 0$
for any $2$-core partition $\lambda$ and consequently

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{ll}
H_2(x \, ;q) 
&\displaystyle = \ 1  \ + \ \sum_{\stackrel{\scriptstyle \text{$2$-cores}}{\lambda \, \ne \, \emptyset}} \, q^{|\lambda|} \\
&\displaystyle = \ 1 \ + \ \sum_{d \geq 1} \, q^{{1 \over 2}d(d+1)} \\
&\displaystyle = \ \prod_{d \geq 1} \big(1 - q^{2d}\big) \cdot \big(1 + q^d \big)
\end{array}
\end{equation}

Furthermore

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{ll}
\log H_2(x \, ; q) 
&\displaystyle = \ 
\sum_{d \geq 1} \, 
\log(1 - q^{2d}) \, + \, \log(1 + q^d) \\
&\displaystyle = \ F_{1 ; 2}(\tau)
\end{array}
\end{equation}

The interesting computation begins with $3$-cores.

**Post-Post Script:** One possible approach to the problem may be to
take advantage of the Garvan-Kim-Stanton correspondence (GKS for short) which is a bijection

\begin{equation}
\lambda \stackrel{\phi}{\Longleftrightarrow} \vec{n}
\end{equation}

between $t$-cores $\lambda$ and integer vectors $\vec{n} = \big(n_0, n_1, \dots, n_{t-1} \big)$ with
zero coordinate sum $n_0 + \cdots + n_{t-1} = 0$ such that

\begin{equation}
|\lambda| \ = \ {t \over 2} \| \vec{n} \|^2 \, + \, \vec{b} \cdot \vec{n}
\end{equation}

where $\vec{b} = \big(0 ,1 , \dots, t-1 \big)$. The trick might be to
express the quantity $\nu_{\scriptscriptstyle T}(\lambda)$ in terms of the coordinates of the corresponding GKS-vector $\vec{n}$.

Consider the case of $3$-cores: If my understanding of O. Brunat and R. Nath's *pointed abacus* construction is correct (see https://arxiv.org/pdf/2101.01512.pdf) a $3$-core partition $\lambda$
with GKS-vector $\vec{n}= \big(n_0, n_1, n_2 \big)$ has an *arm*
of length $3p + r$ with residue $0 \leq r \leq 2$
if and only if $n_r$ is positive and $0 \leq p \leq n_r - 1$. Likewise $\lambda$ will have a *leg* of length $3p + 2 - r$ with $0 \leq r \leq 2$ if and only if $n_r$ is negative and $0 \leq p \leq | n_r | - 1 $.
As mentioned in the comments

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{ll}
\nu_{\scriptscriptstyle T}(\lambda)
&\displaystyle = \ {1 \over 2} \, \sum_{j=1}^k \, \Big(a_j + {1 \over 2} \Big)^2 - \Big(b_j + {1 \over 2} \Big)^2 \\
&\displaystyle = \ \sum_{j=1}^k \,  a_j + {1 \over 2} a_j^2  
\ - \ \sum_{j=1}^k b_j + {1 \over 2} b_j^2 
\end{array}
\end{equation}

where $a_j$ and $b_j$ are the respective $j$-th arm and length lengths
of the partition $\lambda$.
So it should be possible to write $H_3(x \, ; q)$ as a piecewise polynomial function of the GKS-coordinates $n_0$, $n_1$, $n_2$. As illustration consider the situation where $n_0 < 0$ and $n_1 \geq -n_0$ and $n_2 = -n_0 - n_1 \leq 0$ which is one of the of six possible sign configurations of the three GKS-coordinates $n_0$, $n_1$, and $n_2$.
By the Brunat-Nath recipe only $n_1$ will contribute arm lengths
while $n_0$ and $n_2$ will contribute leg lengths. The arm contribution
to $\nu_{\scriptscriptstyle T}(\lambda)$ will be

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{ll}
\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^k a_j + {1 \over 2}a_j^2
&\displaystyle = \ \sum_{p=0}^{n_1 - 1} \, (3p+1) + {1 \over 2}(3p+1)^2 \\
&\displaystyle = \ {1 \over 2} 3n_1 \, + \, 3n_1(n_1-1) \, + \, {3 \over 4}n_1(n_1-1)(2n_1-1)
\end{array}
\end{equation}

while the leg contribution to $\nu_{\scriptscriptstyle T}(\lambda)$ will be

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{l}
\displaystyle 
\sum_{j=1}^k b_j + {1 \over 2}b_j^2 \
\displaystyle 
= \ \left\{
\begin{array}{c}
\displaystyle \sum_{p=0}^{|n_0| -1} \, (3p + 2) + {1 \over 2}(3p+ 2)^2 \\
+ \\
\displaystyle \sum_{p=0}^{|n_2| -1} \, (3p) + {1 \over 2}(3p)^2
\end{array}
\right. \\
= \, \left\{
\begin{array}{c}
\displaystyle -4n_0 \, + \, {9 \over 2}n_0(n_0+1) \, - \, {3 \over 4}n_0(n_0+1)(2n_0+1)  \\
+ \\
\displaystyle {3 \over 2}n_2(n_2+1) \, - \, {3 \over 4}n_2(n_2+1)(2n_2+1)
\end{array}
\right. \\
= \, \left\{
\begin{array}{c}
\displaystyle -4n_0 \, + \, {9 \over 2}n_0(n_0+1) \, - \, {3 \over 4}n_0(n_0+1)(2n_0+1)  \\
+ \\
\displaystyle -{3 \over 2}(n_0+n_1)(1-n_0-n_1) \, + \, {3 \over 4}(n_0+n_1)(1-n_0 -n_1)(1-2n_0 - 2n_1)
\end{array}
\right. \\
\end{array}
\end{equation}

Taking the difference of the arm and leg contributions we get
the value of $\nu_{\scriptscriptstyle T}(\lambda)$ namely

\begin{equation}
\nu_{\scriptscriptstyle T}(\lambda)
\ = \
{1 \over 2}\Big(3n_1^2 - 3n_0^2\big(1 + 3n_1\big) + n_0\big(2 + 3n_1 - 9n_1^2 \big) \Big)
\end{equation}

So the lattice points of the cone in $\Bbb{Z}^2$ cut out by the inequalities $n_0 < 0$ and $n_1 \geq -n_0$ and $n_2 = -n_0 - n_1 \leq 0$
make the following contribution to $H_3(x \, ; q)$

\begin{equation}
\displaystyle
\sum_{n_0 < 0} \sum_{n_1 \geq -n_0} \, q^{3n_0^2 + 3n_1^2 + 3n_0n_1 - 2n_0 - n_1} 
\exp \Big\{ {x \over 2}\Big(3n_1^2 - 3n_0^2\big(1 + 3n_1\big) + n_0\big(2 + 3n_1 - 9n_1^2 \big) \Big) \Big\} 
\end{equation}

A similiar calculation can be undertaken for the remaining five cones
in $\Bbb{Z}^2$. Does anyone recognize this kind of sum?

Comment: We have $\nu_T(\lambda)=\sum {\lambda_i\choose 2}-\sum {\lambda'_i\choose 2}$, though I don't know if this is useful.

Comment: There's also $\nu_{\scriptscriptstyle T} (\lambda) = {1 \over 2} \sum_{i=1}^r  \tilde{a}_i^2 - \tilde{b}_i^2$ where $\lambda = (a_1, \dots, a_r \| b_1, \dots, b_r)$ are the half-integer Frobenius coordinates but this probably is just a reformulation of what you wrote.

Comment: The Murnaghan-Nakayama rule is cancellation-free whenever all strips have equal size, and then there is a hook-formula for computing the actual value: https://www2.math.upenn.edu/~peal/polynomials/borderStripTableaux.htm#borderStripHookFormulas

Comment: Sorry Per, I don't  follow. The Murnaghan-Nakayama rule only involves strips of equal size to begin with. Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Did you mean equal *height* ? I don't see how that will help because, for example, 3-cores will have both vertical and horizontal strips of size 2 --- so there will be cancellations.

Comment: @InesInstitoris The general Murnaghan-Nakayama rule has strips of different sizes. In this particular case (in this question) all strips have equal size. There will not be any cancellation in this case, even though different strips have different heights(!). I would very much love a nice proof of this (all proofs I know uses the quotient map).

Comment: Are we discussing the same Murnaghan-Nakayama rule? The one I had in mind (e.g. on page 59, problem 4.45 of Fulton & Harris) records a sign that depends on the *height* of the strip; the strips in our case will have size 2 and heights which are either 0 or 1.

Comment: @PerAlexandersson Could you compute an example using the general Murnaghan-Nakayama rule (in the answer section ?). Say calculating, without subtraction/cancellation, the value of $\chi^\lambda_{\scriptscriptstyle T}$ using the $3$-core $\lambda = (5,3,1,1)$.

Comment: @PerAlexandersson Are you referring to this formula: $\chi^\lambda_{\sigma} = \mathrm{sgn}(\sigma) \cdot \big| \mathrm{BST}\big( \lambda/\rho, d \big) \big| \cdot \chi^\rho_\mu$ where $\rho$ is the $d$-core of $\lambda$ and $\sigma = d^\ell$ and $\mu \vdash m$ (which partition ?!) and $|\lambda| = d \ell + m$ ?

Comment: @InesInstitoris yes, exactly.

Comment: @PerAlexandersson I don't see how this applies. I want to compute $\chi^\lambda_\sigma$ where $\sigma$ is a single two-cycle *not* a $\ell$-fold product of two-cycles where $|\lambda| = 2 \ell + m$.

Comment: @InesInstitoris Ah, ok, then I misunderstood -- this thing with 3-cores show up naturally when all parts have the same size...

Comment: @PerAlexandersson Thanks for telling me about the BST-formula --- I didn't know it. It's possible that this formula may in fact help; I just don't see how (at the moment), even when $\lambda$ is a $3$-core.

Comment: This is a very naive question, but is your homomorphism $\rho$ written in the wrong direction?  I would have thought it was the fundamental group of the punctured torus mapping to $S_d$.

Comment: @JSE You're right! Thank you, I'll correct that.

Answer (score 2):

This posting shows how to handle the case of $3$-cores
and compute $H_3(x \, ; q)$.

Let's begin with the straight forward observation that $\lambda$ is a $t$-core if and only if its conjugate
partition $\lambda'$ is a $t$-core. Furthermore, taking
advantage of R. Stanley's comment

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{ll}
\nu_{\scriptscriptstyle T}(\lambda) 
&\displaystyle = \ \eta( \lambda) \ - \ \eta(\lambda') \\
&\displaystyle = \ \sum_{i \geq 1} \, 
\binom{\lambda_i}{2} 
\ - \ \sum_{i \geq 1} \, 
\binom{\lambda_i'}{2}
\end{array}
\end{equation}

we see that $\nu_{\scriptscriptstyle T}(\lambda') = -\nu_{\scriptscriptstyle T}(\lambda)$. In particular
$\nu_{\scriptscriptstyle T}(\lambda)$ vanishes when
$\lambda$ is a self-conjugate partition. This means that

\begin{equation}
H_t( x \, ; q) \ = \ 1 + 
\displaystyle  \sum_{\ \lambda \, = \, \lambda'}
\, q^{|\lambda|} 
\ +  \displaystyle \sum_{\nu_{\scriptscriptstyle T}(\lambda) \, > \, 0}
2 \cosh \big\{ \nu_{\scriptscriptstyle T}(\lambda) \, x \big\} \, q^{|\lambda|}
\end{equation}

where the sums are taken over non-empty $t$-core partitions. The self-conjugate $3$-cores
are precisely those $3$-cores whose GKS-vectors
are of the form $(a,0,-a)$ with $a \in \Bbb{Z}$.
For GKS-vectors $(a,0,-a)$ with $a > 0$ the corresponding $3$-core partition $\lambda$ will have size $|\lambda| = a(3a-2)$ and
first part $\lambda_1 = 3a-2$. For GKS-vectors $(-a,0,a)$ with
$a \geq 0$ the corresponding $3$-core partition $\lambda$
will have size $|\lambda| = a(3a+2)$ and first part $\lambda_1 = 3a$. These calculation are made using the Brunat-Nath set-up mentioned
in second post-script of my original post.

The set of $3$-cores can be arranged into the following
triangular hierarchy as depicted on page 142 of
these notes ([https://qcpages.qc.cuny.edu/~chanusa/courses/636/14/notes/636fa14ch50.pdf](https://qcpages.qc.cuny.edu/%7Echanusa/courses/636/14/notes/636fa14ch50.pdf)) by Christopher Hanusa. After
staring at the alcove pattern a bit, I'll
*guess* that (1) a $3$-core partition is
self-conjugate if and only if $\nu_{\scriptscriptstyle T}(\lambda) = 0$
and (2) any $3$-core partition with with positive
$\nu_{\scriptscriptstyle T}$-value can be uniquely expressed as
$\rho^k \cdot \lambda$ where $\lambda = \big(\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_\ell \big)$ is a self-conjugate $3$-core
partition, $k \geq 1$ is an integer, and
$\rho \cdot \lambda := \big(\lambda_1 + 2, \lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_\ell  \big)$. Here $\rho^k \cdot \lambda$ denotes the $k$-fold iteration of $\rho$.

Note that for a general partition $\lambda$ we have

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{rl}
\displaystyle
\big| \rho \cdot \lambda \big| 
&\displaystyle = \ |\lambda| \, + \, \lambda_1 +2  \\
\displaystyle 
\nu_{\scriptscriptstyle T}\big( \rho \cdot \lambda \big)
&\displaystyle = \ \nu_{\scriptscriptstyle T}(\lambda) 
\, - \, |\lambda| \, + \, 
\binom{\lambda_1 +2}{2} 
\end{array}
\end{equation}

and using the Faulhaber formulae it's not too hard to see that

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{rl}
\big| \rho^k \cdot \lambda \big|
&\displaystyle = \
|\lambda| \ + \ k\lambda_1 \ + \ k(k+1) \\
\displaystyle \nu_{\scriptscriptstyle T}\big(\rho^k \cdot \lambda \big) 
&\displaystyle = \ 
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
\displaystyle \ \ \ \, 
\nu_{\scriptscriptstyle T}(\lambda) \, - \, k|\lambda|
\\
\displaystyle
+ \ {1 \over 2} \, k\lambda_1^2 \, + \, {1 \over 2} \, k(k+2)\lambda_1 \\  
\displaystyle + \ {1 \over 6} \, k(k+1)(2k+1)
\end{array}
\right.
\end{array}
\end{equation}

If we iteratively apply $\rho$ to a self-conjugate $3$-core $\lambda$ with GKS-vector $(a,0,-a)$
with $a > 0$ and tally the total contribution to $H_3(x \, ; q)$ made by $\rho^k \cdot \lambda$ and its conjugate partition as $k \geq 1$ varies we get:

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{ll}
G^+_a(x \, ; q) 
&\displaystyle := \
\sum_{k \geq 1} 2 \cosh \big\{ U_+(a,k) \, x \big\}
\, q^{D_+(a,k)} \ \ \text{where} \\
U_+(a,k) 
&\displaystyle := \ 
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
\displaystyle \ \ \ \, {1 \over 2} \, (a-2)(3a-2)k \\
\displaystyle + \ {1 \over 2} \, (3a-2)k(k+2) \\
\displaystyle + \ {1 \over 6} \, k(k+1)(2k+1)  
\end{array}
\right. \\
D_+(a,k)
&\displaystyle = \ a(3a-2) \ + \ (3a-1)k \ + \ k^2
\end{array}
\end{equation}

Similarly the total contribution to $H_3(x \, ; q)$ made by $\rho^k \cdot \lambda$ and its conjugate partition as $k \geq 1$ varies and where $\lambda$ is
a self-conjugate $3$-core with GKS-vector
$(-a,0,a)$ and $a \geq 0$ is:

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{ll}
G^{-}_a(x \, ; q) 
&\displaystyle := \
\sum_{k \geq 1} 2 \cosh \big\{ U_{-}(a,k) \, x \big\}
\, q^{D_{-}(a,k)} \ \ \text{where} \\
U_{-}(a,k) 
&\displaystyle := \ 
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
\displaystyle \ \ \ \, {1 \over 2} \, a(3a-4)k \\
\displaystyle + \ {3 \over 2} \, ak(k+2) \\
\displaystyle + \ {1 \over 6} \, k(k+1)(2k+1)  
\end{array}
\right. \\
D_{-}(a,k)
&\displaystyle = \ a(3a+2) \ + \ (3a+1)k \ + \ k^2
\end{array}
\end{equation}

The self-conjugate $3$-cores on the own
make a contribution of

\begin{equation}
G(q) \ = \ 1 + \ \sum_{a \, > \, 0} \ q^{a(3a+2)} \ + \ q^{a(3a-2)}
\end{equation}

and thus, when taken altogether, we get

\begin{equation}
H_3(x \, ; q) \ = \
G(q) \ + \ \sum_{a > 0} G^+_a(x \, ; q ) 
\ + \sum_{a \geq 0} G^{-}_a(x \, ; q) 
\end{equation}

Perhaps the right-hand sum will be familiar to
the readership of this posting.